# Gradle Project import in progress In Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am very new to Android Studio

I am trying to run simple HelloWorld Program in Android Studio

I am getting this message in Editor

"Gradle Project import in progress"

How to resolve this?

Comment: If you are using first time it will take some time to download all gradle stuff in your local machine so wait for some time to complete.

Comment: I waited for around 45 mins. It is still shwoing the progress bar "Building project info"

Comment: It's likely some sort of network problem then. If you use a proxy server then you'll need to configure that, or there could be other connectivity issues.

Comment: if you are on windows let me know if you have any zip file under directory `C:\Users\your_username\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-1.10-all\6vpvhqu0efs1fqmqr2decq1v12` . If not I will give you workaround to solve the issue.

Comment: Extract it to check whether it is downloaded completely or not.